# Add some specific value to another list in Python

Tags: python, list

I'm new to programming and I've been trying to do some exercises.

After reading 5 letters, I would like to add to a new list only the vowels one.

I've been struggling to do that but I couldn't. Here is my - not working - script:

```
list = []
vowels = []

for i in range(5):
    list.append(str(input('Add a letter: ')))
    for j in list:
      if 'aeiou' in list:
          vowels.append(list[:])
print(vowels)
```

It turns out that when I print vowels I get an empty list [].

Can you guys let me know where I'm making a mistake?

Please bear with me, I'm very new to programming and still getting to know how it works.

Many thanks!

Comment: `if any(letter in list for letter in 'aeiou')`?

Comment: Hey @Felipe, welcome to SO, can you please explain briefly what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

This might be a solution but I was unable to fully understand what you are trying to do.

```
letter_list = []
vowels = []

for i in range(5):
    letter_list.append(str(input('Add a letter: ')))



for j in letter_list:
    if any([i in j for i in 'aeiou']):
        vowels.append(j)


print(vowels)
```

Or without pythonic part in the if statement.

```
letter_list = []
vowels = []

for i in range(5):
    letter_list.append(str(input('Add a letter: ')))


for j in letter_list:
    if 'a' in j or 'e' in j or 'i' in j or 'o' in j or 'u' in j:
        vowels.append(j)


print(vowels)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question properly then you're looking for the following:

```
found_vowels = []
vowels = ['a','e','i','o','u']

for i in range(5):
    letter = input('Enter a letter: ')
    if letter in vowels:
        found_vowels.append(letter)
print(f"The vowels you entered are {found_vowels}")
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your statement, if you need to first read the 5 letter and then decide which one are vowels, then you can have 2 separate loops:

```
mlist = []
vowels = []

for i in range(5):
    mlist.append(input('Add a letter: '))

# Copying in a second list just the vowels
for j in mlist:
      if j in 'aeiou':
          vowels.append(j)

print(vowels)
```

In case you would like to segregate between vowels and consonants you could solve it as follow:

```
vowels = []
consonants= []

for i in range(5):
    letter = input('Add a letter: ')
    if letter in 'aeiou':
        vowels.append(letter)
    else:
        consonants.append(letter)
        
print(vowels)
print(consonants)
```